# PostgreSQL - Why can't I create composite foreign key based on unique column without declaring composite key as unique?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint, composite-key

I've noticed that you cannot create a foreign key if the referenced key isn't unique, but, if I have records `(x, y, z)` where `x` is unique, it is "intuitive" to assume that every record will always be unique.

So, is it there any particular reason I have not considered for why I can't do something like this

```
create table x(
    id int primary key,
    something int not null
);
create table y(
    id serial primary key, -- whatever, this doesn't matter
    x_id int not null,
    x_something int not null,
    foreign key (x_id, x_something)
        references x(id, something)
);
```

in Postgres which throws

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "x"
```

and which can be corrected adding `unique (id, something)` in table `x`.

Is this behavior just present in Postgres, or is something defined in the SQL standard?

Is there any way to reference the composite key without requiring the `unique` constraint?

**EDIT 1:**
Here is an example of a situation in which this would be useful

```
create table movie_reservation(
    id serial primary key,
    movie_id int references(...),
    -- ... (reservation data like the time and interval),
    seen boolean not null default false -- wether a user has seen it
);
-- want califications of moves that HAVE BEEN SEEN
create table movie_calification(
    movie_reservation_id int not null,
    seen boolean
      not null
      check (boolean = true),
    stars smallint
        not null
        check (stars between 1 and 5),


    foreign key (movie_reservation_id, seen)
        references movie_reservation(id, seen)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Most databases require that a foreign key constraint be to a primary key or unique key (either of which can be composite).

I am not aware of extended capabilities that allow a superset of columns from a primary or unique key.  Perhaps some databases do allow it.  On the other hand, I cannot readily think of a use for using additional secondary keys, when a smaller set works.

(Caveat:  I actually can think of a situation, but Postgres has table inheritance making that use unnecessary.)

Comment: +1 for metioning table inheritance, I didn't know such functionality, wich also solves my particular problem. Thank you!